# OauthPrompt does not navigate to the signIn page on Teams

Tags: azure, botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I am adding OAuth authentication to the Bot, which will be installed in MS Teams channel, I am following the setup described in this [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/46.teams-auth). This setup implements the OAuthPrompt Dialog along with Waterfalls dialog. when tested from Web Chat (provided in Bot service) however, upon installing in MS Teams the bot fails to open the signin url from OAuthPromt dialog.

Following is my setup

Azure Bot Service with Azure AD V1 identity service provider

Azure App services, Windows stack, dotnet core 2.2

Azure App registration with `https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect`

bot manifest.json with valid domain as `token.botframework.com` and `online.microsoftlogin.com`

Debugging.

I tried to use Fiddler to see the outgoing request from Teams to `token.botframework.com/api/oauth/signin=12345` , however i did not see any requests being made to this domain from Teams.

Could someone please help in figuring out, the issue?
Is there a better way of debugging?

Thanks

Comment: did you get any errors on the Channels Health tab of the bot on Azure? you can try making use of [ngrok](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/) and add breakpoints in your code to see what might be causing the issue.

Comment: Hi, I figured it out, apparently the bot service and app service were two different app service plans, moving them to single plan worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue where login only worked in tester in portal and not in teams, and that was because I had an old app with wrong manifest on same name or whenm I forgot to upload it to teams at all.